# How to make google play accept cordova app?

Tags: android, apache, cordova, cordova-plugins

I already checked several answers related to the same issue, but couldn't find a proper solution:

**Issue or problem:**

After updating some pages in my cordova app (android only so far), i tried to submit my app to the google play store again.

After uploading the apk (no matter if as beta or production version), i always get a notofication mail saying that the app was rejected due to vulnerabilities:

> Apache Cordova
>
> The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.
>
> You can find information about how to upgrade in this Google Help Center article.
>
> APK Version    38

The google help center page links to an apache documentation on how to [upgrade cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html). 
I followed the steps there and now have pretty recent versions of cordova and the android platform running:

output of **cordova platform ls**:

```
Installed platforms:
  android 5.0.0
Available platforms: 
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  ios ~4.4.0
  osx ~4.0.1
  webos ~3.7.0
```

output for **cordova -v**:

```
7.0.1
```

Since i read somewhere that it might be an Issue with a plugin, i updated the plugins as well:

output of **cordova plugins ls**:

```
com.hiddentao.cordova.filepath 1.0.0 "FilePath"
com.virtualartifacts.webintent 1.0.0 "WebIntent"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

Since i learned that it might be an issue with the CSP inside the index.html, i changed this as well, but to no success:

**Content-Security-Policy part in index.html:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src * ; connect-src https://MYSERVER.URL">
```

so from my point of view all the platform specific parts should be up to date. I still can't upload the app to google play without being rejected.

Anyone has an idea or hint on how to make this work again?

Comment: Are you supporting Android phones that are below KitKat? I once had a similar issue and once I made it available for KitKat+ only, it went away.

Comment: @Raymond: Just tried switching to SDK Version 19, which is Kitkat (4.4), but it still does not work. Any other ideas?